# Returning contents of template tag as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web-component, html5-template

I was wondering if there was a way of getting the contents of the elements within a template tag and returning it as a string?  At the moment it seems like it is returning something along the lines on `[object document fragment]` but want just the html content inside.

```
function CreateWidget(widget) {
    //Check if browser supports templates
    if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {
        //Grab the template's content and assign it to a variable so we only have the gut of the template
        var widgetContent = document.querySelector('#panel-template').content //('#panel-template').get(1).setAttribute('id', widget.WidgetCode);
        widgetContent.querySelector('#chart').setAttribute('id', widget.WidgetCode);

        //get the overlay toolbar
        var widgetOverlay = widgetContent.querySelector('.overlayed');
        widgetOverlay.setAttribute('data-render', widget.WidgetCode);
        widgetOverlay.setAttribute('data-chartType', widget.chartType);
        widgetOverlay.setAttribute('data-devID', widget.deviceID);
        widgetOverlay.setAttribute('data-metricType', widget.metricType);
        widgetOverlay.setAttribute('data-title', widget.WidgetName);

        var el = document.importNode(widgetContent, true);
        alert(el);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If all you want is the HTML as a string, you can get that with just the usual `.innerHTML`:

```
document.querySelector("template").innerHTML
```

If you instead want the `textContent`, you can get that from `.content.textContent`; like this:

```
document.querySelector("template").content.textContent
```

If you want to actually iterate over the `template` child nodes or do much else of anything with its content, you need to use that `.content` property, which returns a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

From that you have `children`, `firstElementChild`, `lastElementChild`, `childElementCount`, and `find()`, `findAll()`,  `querySelector()`, `querySelectorAll()`, `getElementById`; at least eventually—other than the `query*` methods and `getElementById()`. Not sure if Safari supports most of it yet (ca. 2015-10). And I think nobody yet supports `find()`/`findAll()`.

Comment: I want to be able to change the contents of the HTML within the template and then return the HTML as a string, can I do that with the innerHTML property?

Comment: Sure—if you try setting it with `document.querySelector("template").innerHTML = "<div>Some new content</div>"` and then getting it with `var foo = document.querySelector("template").innerHTML` I think you’ll find it works as you’d expect.