# Get <template> tag content verbatim?

Tags: javascript, html

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32833931/65387), but that answer actually transforms the template contents. e.g.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('t').innerHTML);
console.log(document.getElementById('t').content.textContent);
```

```html
<template id="t">
<p>i <3 cheese</p>
</template>
```

This outputs

```
<p>i &lt;3 cheese</p>
i <3 cheese
```

What I want back is:

```
<p>i <3 cheese</p>
```

i.e., exactly what's between `<template>` and `</template>`.

Is there a way to get that?

Comment: Probably not. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905503/218196

Comment: `<p>i <3 cheese</p>` is invalid HTML, so someone (probably your browser) is actually doing you a favor converting it into an entity.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Perhaps. But what if I wasn't writing HTML inside of my `<template>`? What if my template language was something completely different? Should the browser really be getting clever?

Comment: `<template>` is expected to contain valid HTML like any other part of the document. If you want non-HTML templates you need to store them some way else, in JS variables or seperate files for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suddenly occurred to me that I could just use a script tag.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('t').innerHTML);
```

```html
<script id="t" type="text/my-template-language">
<p>i <3 cheese</p>
</script>
```